# Detect when asked and granted permission to iOS notifications?

Tags: ios, permissions, notifications

In the iOS client when you first run it you get a UIAlert asking for permission to grant access to send this person notifications.

I'm wondering if its possible to first:

1. Catch when this alert will fire (before it happens)
2. Catch what response is given (cancel or ok) (after it happens)

Is there such a way to get callbacks for the above two scenarios?

Many thanks

Comment: To give context -- I wish to use it in combination with a Mixpanel or event handling; so if the user is asked for permission send an event to Mixpanel and when the user has accepted permission; send an event to Mixpanel

Comment: Does Mixpanel ask for this permission for your app?

Comment: No, it does not @Gal; rather the app asks for Permission then sends this data (hopefully) to mixpanel.  I want to capture it before and after it has been accepted

Comment: If you are the app developer AND you are registering to the APNs, then read my answer below. **Before** is when you call `- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications` and **after** is when you get the callback in `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings`. If you found my answer helpful, please up-vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS 8 and later, implement the following method in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {

    // You could check here [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]

    // This is where you set up your local notification
}
```

This method is a `UIApplicationDelegate` method, so all you need to do is implement it in your `MyAppDelegate.m` file.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:):

> Tells the delegate what types of notifications may be used to get the user’s attention.
>
> Parameters
>
> application: The app object that registered the user notification settings.
>
> notificationSettings: The user notification settings that are available to your app.
>
> The settings in this object may be different than the ones you originally requested.
>
> Discussion
>
> Apps that use local or remote notifications to alert the user to new information must register the types of notifications they want to use by calling the registerUserNotificationSettings: method of the app object. (In apps that link on versions of iOS prior to 8.0, registration can also happen implicitly when you schedule a local notification.) Your app’s request is combined with the user’s current preferences to determine what notification types are allowed and the results are delivered to this method in the notificationSettings parameter.
>
> The first time you register your app’s preferred notification types, the system asks the user whether your app should be allowed to deliver notifications and stores the user’s response. The system does not prompt the user during subsequent registration attempts. The user can always change the notification preferences using the Settings app.
>
> Because the user’s preferences can change, you should always check the contents of the notificationSettings parameter. These settings control only whether the user is notified about a local or remote notification. The notification is still delivered to your app at the appropriate times.

Comment: This is helpful and upvoted.  Our notifications are already setup and they work fine iOS8 and below; I'm really after a way of grabbing callbacks of before acceptance and accepted state for Mixpanel events

Comment: pleased that it helped you. Happy coding.

Comment: Does Mixpanel ask for this permission for your app?

Comment: Pardon. couldn't get what you are saying

Comment: I understand you are are using Mixpanel SDK in your application, right?

Comment: i suppose that is for @AtillaJax

Comment: Yes, we are using MixPanel SDK.   Mixpanel does not ask for permission; rather the app does and then sends this report to MixPanel

Answer (score 1):

The application itself is causing the alert to pop, so you don't need to "catch" anything.

Once you call `- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications`, the OS will fire the alert.

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotifications) for more details.