# How to detect a user granting Photos access?

Tags: ios, permissions, privacy, photo-gallery

I've got an app on iOS that requires access to the Photo Library on the initial view.  It works perfectly every time, except for the VERY first time someone loads the app: when the OS asks for permission to access the user's photos, it's already loaded the view underneath that alert, but it obviously doesn't have the photos to load it properly.

It would be a simple thing to reload the view content once the user grants permission, but I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding a method that is called when that happens.

Is there a method call, or some other way, to detect the moment a user grants permission for an app to access the Photo Library?  I've found a [few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28606203/1418688) that [seemed promising](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14742578/1418688), but nothing that actually addresses this issue...

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803217/presenting-camera-permission-dialog-in-ios-8. May be it will help you

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651863/how-to-know-that-application-have-camera-access-or-not-pragmatically-in-ios8